# How to use "Approximate String Matching" with Solr 5.x>?

Tags: solr

There are a variety of algorithms for string matching, such as metaphone, soundex, levenshtein, etc.

- Does Solr have similar algorithms?
- How does Solr work with these algorithms?
- How to configure it?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Solr has [Analyzers, Tokenizers and Filters](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers%2C+Tokenizers%2C+and+Filters) for that purpose. You can define how you tokenize your data and how the query the query is parsed in a file called schema.xml or adhere to field naming as per the managedschema file present in the conf directory of the core. This [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers%2C+Tokenizers%2C+and+Filters) also describes how to use and what to expect when using various analyzers, tokenizers, etc with examples. You can also use the analysis tool in GUI for the same.

Comment: Thanks @kretan the Reference Guide is very helpful, let me try it.

Comment: The *full* list of the components is also available at [the Solr Start website](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/).